# How do I get a bar chart by pandas dataframe axis python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Consider the following dataframe, this is what it looks like on jupyter notebook:

```
in(1): df

out(1):

months          0   1   3   6   12

        name                    
------------------------------------
     janedoe    1.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 1.0
     johndoe    3.0 2.0 3.0 1.0 1.0
     tfbundy    1.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0
     someone    1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 4.0
     another    1.0 2.0 2.0 3.0 2.0
         ...    ... ... ... ... ...
```

etc 700 rows. I wish to create a bar chart with stdev error bars where on the y-axis is the mean score (1.0, 3.0 etc) of each month column and on the x-axis are the months (0,1,3,6,12). How do I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be through [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html), as it creates error bars and other nice stuff.

First, melt the DataFrame:

```
m = pd.melt(df).rename(columns={'variable': 'month'})
```

This will create a DataFrame with two columns: `month` and `value`. Now plot it:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.barplot(x='month', y='value', data=m)
```

For the data in your sample, it will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved my problem. Didn't occur to me to melt the dataframe.